# Ambient Light Rejection

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Context:

> Ambient Light Rejection: XXXX lux (Direct Sun-light), YYYY lux
>   (Fluorescent Light)

How to translate better: Umgebungslichtabschirmung or Tageslichtunterdrückung?

Comment: Depending on exact context, Filter might be used as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short google search shows, that the term `ambient light rejection` is mostly used for `ambient light rejection screens`. So

1. It should be `Umgebungslicht` rather than `Tageslicht` as the ambient light can have different sources.
2. It's rather not an `Abschirmung`. `Abschirmung` is used for the rejection of transmission, regardless if this is done by reflection or absorption. `Unterdrückung` can mean both, so you should use this.

> Umgebungslichtunterdrückung